# How to find those which have the same properties with the other one

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am just a green hand of the neo4j, so what I want to figure out is how to get the columns which have the same year and on the same team of one player. You can see the codes as follow:

```
MATCH (n:Player)-[r:APPEARANCE]->(t:Team)
WHERE t.team_id AND r.year = 
(MATCH (n:Player {player_id: 'napolmi01'})-[r:APPEARANCE]->(t:Team))
RETURN t.team_id, r.year)
RETURN n.player_id, t.team_id, r.year
```

But this is not the right answer obviously, so how to modify it?
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you tried uses a subquery which is not (yet) supported by Cypher, but it can be expressed using the [`WITH`](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/with/) clause:

```
MATCH (:Player {player_id: 'napolmi01'})-[r1:APPEARANCE]->(t:Team)
WITH t, r1
MATCH (n:Player)-[r2:APPEARANCE {year: r1.year}]->(t)
RETURN n.player_id, t.team_id, r2.year
```

Also, as there are no aggregations involved, you can simply use a query without a `WITH` clause:

```
MATCH (:Player {player_id: 'napolmi01'})-[r1:APPEARANCE]->(t:Team)
  <-[r2:APPEARANCE]->(n:Player)
WHERE r1.year = r2.year
RETURN n.player_id, t.team_id, r1.year
```

**Update.** If you have duplicate results, use `RETURN DISTINCT n.player_id, t.team_id, r1.year`

Comment: oh, thanks a lot but what I want is not only the same team but also the same year at the same team, so it should satisfy these 2 constraints at the same time...

Comment: thank you for your answer and the modification of my question description, I test the code and there is something strange is that the same player will appear twice, I don' t know why......

Comment: That is indeed strange. First, try `RETURN DISTINCT` to see if duplicates go away.